# Correct hashcode implementation for Colors

Tags: java, hashcode

I have a class:

```
public class Color {
    private double red;
    private double green;
    private double blue;
}
```

with such *equals* method:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Color color = (Color) o;

    if (Math.abs(color.red - red) < COLOR_TRESHOLD) {
        return false;
    }
    if (Math.abs(color.green - green) < COLOR_TRESHOLD) {
        return false;
    }
    return Math.abs(color.blue - blue) < COLOR_TRESHOLD;
}
```

So, as you can see I would like similar colors to be equivalent.
My question is how to create correct *hashcode* implementation for this case. 
Of course I could return constant value. But it seems to be not a good idea.

Comment: Your `equals()` method breaks transitivity. Why would you use `double` anyway?

Comment: Thats not a consistent implementation of `.equals()`, it does not have the transitive property. Basically if x.equals(y) and y.equals(z), x needs to be equal to z.

Comment: Your equals() method is invalid. It doesn respect the transitivity contract: if a equals b and b equals c, then a should equal c. That won't happen with that implementation. Use equals for equality. Use another, dedicated method to determine if two colors are "close".

Comment: @JBNizet @shmosel @k5_ Thanks guys, I forgot about transient property of `equlas`

Answer (score 1):

You should put:

```
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

As the first test. Sometimes if a null is passed and it's not the first thing checked for you can get a null pointer exception.

Comment: No. If a null value is passed for `o` in the example, it will basically check `if ( this == null )`. Which is perfectly fine, wont cause a null pointer and will evaluate to `false`, since `this` can never be null.

Comment: I've had npe's before in that scenario but I got into the habit of that order a long time ago so I guess it could have been the compiler I was using.